# Copying workspace in windows node from master at declarative pipeline stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, nodes

Is it possible to have the same code, which was checked out at the first stage of pipeline jobs & passes through the various other stages running on same node, copied to a Windows node? The Windows node is using "JNLP" to connect to master.

I am running a batch file to invoke some Selenium test cases locally on a Windows box and by doing this I am missing the updated test script at source code.

I am expecting in some way if I can copy the already created workspace into other nodes from master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [stash](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#-stash-%20stash%20some%20files%20to%20be%20used%20later%20in%20the%20build) and unstash mechanism. This is capable of moving a lot of data. It might take a while for very large workspaces but it can be done.

In my case I once made a mistake where I used the `includes` instead of `include`. This resulted in all files being stashed, around 4GB! It was a bit slow (10 minutes), but I was very impressed it worked without crashing the server or slave.